# How to dynamically run process in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, twitter

I am designing a website and it uses Windows Forms (in Visual Studio 10) in which **for example i have five-six URLs**. Now i am displaying them on home page of my website xyz.com

What i want is, i want to calculate total no. of tweets for all links and display links based on no. of times they are being tweeted/retweeted.

for a url we can calculate no. of tweet using twitter api http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=YourURL

I know all the stuff like receiving JSON values in a string and parsing json to retrieve tweet counts and then compare and display links based on the priority etc.

What i have been using till now it is initiating all the process using a Click_Button.

But i want to know how can i automate this all for each 10 minutes. Its like a end user can see urls priority with just refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If timing itself is not important (it doesn't have to be 10 minutes precisely), I would suggest binding to any event that fires when users use your application. No point in calculating anything if noone is using it :-)

So you could use a login, or page load, or whatever happens at an interval roughly like the interval you wish to achieve.

You can always store a DateTime variable somewhere that you can check to see when the calculation was last made. Something like:

```
public void MyEventHasFired()
{
     DateTime dateLastProcessed = ... //Database? Session data? Anything goes.
     if(dateLastProcessed < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
     {
          //calculate

          ...

          dateLastProcessed = DateTime.Now;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to run a scheduled task ever 10 mins which interacts with the DB.  The web application also interacts with the DB and thus the two systems are distinct.

Side note: it is strongly recommended to use only console applications as scheduled tasks.  If you make a windows form application will will have some issues.

---

As Kieren Johnstone has pointed out in another answer the best way to do this would be to write a windows service.

I still recommend the solution as described above as a first step since it is easy to debug and test.

Additionally, give some serious consideration to logging and error reporting -- with background tasks you can never know to much about what the heck it was doing when it broke.

Comment: I haven't taken this route in a while, but I believe this may have the effect of a console app popping up on the console session of the machine the task is scheduled (I may be wrong?).  I had this before when scheduling a batch file, I would guess it's the same for console apps.

Comment: This is an option you can turn on or off when setting up the task.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is definitely a Windows Service.  It can be started, stopped and managed well, it's easy to log, maintain..

Scheduled Tasks are very prone to problems.  At least in a Windows Service you can configure it to start automatically, re-start if there's a problem, you can control the timing yourself in the code, and catch/handle exceptions as you wish.

Comment: Scheduled tasks may be prone to problems, but so is writing your own scheduling code in a Windows service - not a simple task for the inexperienced. Might as well use the Windows scheduler rather than reinventing the wheel (and probably getting it wrong).

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(15 * 60 * 1000);` is all the scheduling code you need.  Does that invalidate your point?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - I think using the scheduler to do the first version is the right way to go.  The code can then be upgraded to be a service once the functionality has been tested.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - Also, your code snippet is not the same, this will wait for 10 mins to run the next time as op. to running every 10 mins.

Comment: The task scheduler was invented for system administrators to defrag, move files, perform backups.  Windows Services were invented for processing tasks that are monitored, controlled and integrated tightly into the OS.  While it might be easy to schedule a console app to run, if you use a Windows Service all exceptions will (by default) be logged to the event log.  Using the Task Scheduler is bad, full of holes, and just asking for pain.  Having done this many times, I'm afraid I have to stick to my guns on this.

Comment: (And yes, I realise it will wait 10 minutes after execution, but the impression given is that it needs to happen 'every so often' or 'fairly frequently'.  I was demonstrating that 'scheduling' code isn't difficult, in fact if you had to identify one of the easiest possible problems/algorithms, this would be right up there ;))

Comment: You convinced me, changing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best scheduler i know is [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

It'is not simple to use but it works great.

You can find an example with asp.net there http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/ASPNET-Scheduled-Tasks-with-QuartzNET.aspx

Anyway i agree with Kieren Johnstone: you should use a windows service